# How to Capture Locked Cursor Movement?

Tags: c#, events

Using the Cursor object, setting the Clip to `new Rectangle(Cursor.Position, new Size(1, 1)`, to prevent mouse movement, I found out that Control's MouseMove event would only raise if the cursor were to move on the form; dismissing physical mouse movement. By what means would I be able to both lock and listen for physical mouse movement, as it's done in most 3D games & software?

Comment: You can hide the cursor!!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, not show the cursor to user. This is pretty easy.

```
Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.None;
```

or in XAML code behind,

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.None;
```